# Can an incumbent Vice President vote in a contingent election in which (s)he is a candidate?

Tags: united-states, senate, contested-election

If no Vice Presidential candidate gets a majority of votes in the Electoral College, a Contingent Election will be held in the Senate to elect a new VP.

Normally, if a vote in the Senate is tied, then the VP (as President of the Senate) casts a tie-breaking vote.  However, if the incumbent VP is also a candidate in a contingent election, this can be seen as a conflict of interest.

Is there anything in the US Constitution, US Code, Rules of the Senate, or elsewhere, that would require the VP to recuse him/herself from such a vote?  Or would (s)he be able to vote regardless?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You currently need 51 *senators*: a majority of the whole number of senators period. This has never been tested though, so we don't have a concrete precedence or procedure to say with 100% certainty. The text, to me, seems clear though:

**12th amendment**

> the Senate shall choose the Vice-President; a quorum for the purpose
> shall consist of two-thirds of the whole number of Senators, and a
> majority of the whole number shall be necessary to a choice.

**According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingent_election#:%7E:text=In%20the%20United%20States%2C%20a,president%20of%20the%20United%20States.)**

> "The explicit constitutional language about election by a
> majority of the whole number of senators may preclude the sitting vice
> president from breaking any tie which might occur, although some
> academics and journalists have speculated to the contrary."

Comment: That seems pretty clear that 50-50 is a loss and not a tie.

Comment: @JoeW A loss for who? Someone has to win.

Comment: @Daniel What I mean by that is if the vote is 50-50 there is no winner and they have to keep voting until it is 51-49.

Comment: Or until the President takes office and nominates a new VP to fill the open position (subject to Senate confirmation, which could end up back in the same spot).